# Use RMagick to tell if a jpeg has a clipping path

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I've done some googling but can't find an answer to this. Using identify -verbose, I can see if a jpeg has clipping paths or not. How can I check this with RMagick? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clip), you'll see that the command line tools have a few clipping related options:

`-clip` - `Apply the clipping path if one is present`

`-clip-mask` - `Clip the image as defined by this mask`

`-clip-path` - `Clip along a named path from the 8BIM profile`

However, if you look at [RMagick's documentation](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/optequiv.html), you'll see that the `-clip` and `-clip-path` have no equivalent RMagick commands.

Comment: I don't really need to perform clipping path operations, I only need to know if a jpeg contains a clipping path. I assume this isn't possible either as I can't see identify -verbose anywhere in the RMagick documentation either.